# View to show/hide row values based on another table in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with customer contact data, for example:

```
cust_id tel_no email
cust1   234238 a@a.com
cust2   423443 a@ab.com
cust3   234238 d@a.com
```

I have a table which shows which channels not to use for specific customers (lets call it optout)

```
cust_id channel
cust1   tel_no
cust2   tel_no
cust2   email
cust3   email
```

I'd like to create a view in SQL which would hide contact data in the first table based on the customer/channel combination from the optout table so that the result looks like this:

```
cust_id tel_no email
cust1          a@a.com
cust2   
cust3   234238
```

Whats the best way to achieve this? I was thinking about something like 
    `case when cust1 in (select cust_id from optout where channel = 'tel_no')`
as a check for each field but it would probably be to inneficient if there is like 500k customers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT c.cust_id,
    nvl2( q.tel_no, null, c.tel_no ) tel_no,
    nvl2( q.email, null, c.email ) email
FROM contact_data c
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT cust_id,
      min(case channel when 'tel_no' then 1 end) tel_no,
      min(case channel when 'email' then 1 end) email
  FROM opt
  GROUP BY cust_id 
) q
ON c.cust_id = q.cust_id
ORDER BY c.cust_id
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e890c/8

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the answer and for  demo link as well, this sqlfiddle thing looks useful.